# Why doesn't my For-loop work?

Tags: procedural-programming

I have the mathematica command

```
For[
  Vexp = 11.8; T = 293; Vcal=(0.08314* T/p); p = 81.5*10^-2,
  p < 10,
  p += 0.4, 
  SD = [(Vexp - Vcal/Vexp)]];
  If[SD < 0.5, Print[SD];
```

But this command is not run in mathematica. anyone can help me? I want to print SD when it is < 0.5. how can I write this command in mathematica. Or run this command by while or .... commands.

Comment: Remove square brackets in SD. `SD = (Vexp - Vcal/Vexp)`

Comment: Please modify my code to get answer

Comment: See updated answer below

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

There are many syntax errors in your code, but even with those fixed you would see no values of `SD` printed because `SD` in never less than 0.5.

Evaluate this revised, syntactically correct code and see what you get.

```
Vexp = 11.8; T = 293;
For[p = 81.5*10^-2, p < 10, p += 0.4,
  Vcal = 0.08314*T/p;
  SD = (Vexp - Vcal/Vexp); 
  Print[SD]]
```

#### Update

It is possible that this

```
Vexp = 11.8; T = 293;
For[p = 81.5*10^-2, p < 10, p += 0.4, 
  Vcal = 0.08314*T/p;
  SD = (Vexp - Vcal)/Vexp;
  If[SD < .5, Print[SD]]]
```

is the For-loop you are looking for. It produces

[image: results]